# share notes across devices - with notifications

Tags: windows, note-taking

I am looking for an application to share my notes/TODOs across multiple windows devices - yes, there are plenty of them, but what I am specifically looking for is to write a note on one device and I receive a notification on the second device, that new note has been added

real life example - I write note on my computer at work, I come home and open up my PC - and I receive a notification about my previous note from work

thanks
igor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) would do this - there's browser extensions for firefox,chrome and a native client on the desktop, and it lets you create notes. Now the trick here is that it considers all *firefox* extension clients to be the same 'device' so the note'll open up on all devices with firefox and the extension installed. Alternately, you could send it to a specific computer with the desktop client.

For extra credit (so to speak), and much more flexibility, you could use evernote or another supported service with [IFTT](https://ifttt.com) and just use pushbullet for notifications

Comment: thanks, Pushbullet does the job perfectly